# specify 2 filetypes (endings) for a "for loop"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

is it possible to run a "for f in $files" with several "endings" on files?

if I for example want to run a loop on all *.jpg and *.png inside a directory?

to run for one ending (jpg) you can use

```
path="/tmp/"
FILES="$path"*.jpg
for f in $FILES; do 
echo "filename: $f"
done
```

but to run two, is there something like:

```
path="/tmp/"
FILES="$path"*.jpg||*.png
for f in $FILES; do 
echo "filename: $f"
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use syntax like the following:

```
for f in /tmp/*.{jpg,png}; do
    echo "filename: $f"
done
```

Update:

For better handling of the case when there is no file matching the pattern, you might try Pathname Expansion instead of Brace Expansion:

```
for f in *.@(jpg|png); do
    echo "filename: $f"
done
```

From what I understand, Brace Expansions can expand to file names that don't exist, while Pathname Expansions...can...not...?

Comment: .. then it will cycle thru all .jpg and .png files?

Comment: I think so? More info is under the bash man page under Brace Expansion.

Comment: just read it, look like greek to me (assuming I'm not greek), I'll simply will have to test if    ` for f in "$mdir$sdir/"*.{jpg,png}; do `   works... ... and it did! 

Comment: unfortunately, if I run:...for f in "$mdir$sdir/"*.{jpg,png}; do... and no jpg files exists, it tries to run one loop with the filename "*.jpg", which causes havock on my script..

Comment: Maybe you can test for the existence of the file in the loop using `if [[ -e $f ]]; then`. See `man bash` section "Conditional Expressions".

Comment: ops, my mistake, I actually do run  ' if [[ ! -f $f ]]; then continue;fi ' but a few lines down, and then the issue already had broken the script..

Comment: It looks like from the man page that you might be able to do something like `for f in *.@(jpg|png); do`, but I'm less familiar with that. It's under "Pathname Expansion".